# Selenium IDE - How to get all element with id contains a suffix

Tags: selenium-ide

I have some div with id is contains a suffix '_status' , example :

```
<div id='0_status' class = 'ok_status'/>
<div id='1_status' class = 'ok_status'/>
<div id='2_status' class = 'ok_status'/>
<div id='3_status' class = 'ok_status'/>
```

How to assert that all above div element contains class 'ok_status' ?
I'm using Selenium IDE on Firefox

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like `assertElementPresent | //div[@id='0_status'][@class='ok_status'] |`, for each of the `div`s.